# Add new field to sales_flat_quote_item and save data

Tags: magento

I created a new column in table `sales_flat_quote_item` called 'wiid'. I want to save data in this field when any product form wishlist is added to cart. So, here is my MageWishlist_Model_Item:

```
$quote_item  = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product)->getId());
//I log() this $quote_item and is returning the correct object
$quote_item_id = $quote_item->getId();
//Is returning the correct quote item id  from database
$wishlist_item_id = $this->getId();
//Is returnig the correct wishlist item id 
$quote_item->setWiid($wishlist_item_id);
$quote_item->save();
```

The problem is in last two lines above. It's not saving in database.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I assume that after you created this column you did a complete cache refresh.  Magento caches the structure of your tables, if you don't clear cache it doesn't see the field "wiid".

Comment: try to delete all in `var/cache`

The informations about the table columns are cached there from `Zend_Db`. The normal case is, that `Zend_Db` doesn't know to save the data. If the data is set and the column exists, it will be saved. as Ian said

Comment: Is this issue solved?? If Yes, What was the solution? I m also facing the same issue. Values doesnt store to database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush 'Cache Storage' on backend every time you add a new field on database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way.

Direclty by using sql statement:

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$query = "UPDATE sales_flat_quote_item SET your_field_here = '" . $yourContent . "' where item_id = ". $itemId;
$write->query($query);
```

OR instead of get quote_item model  you have to get quote model and iterate through items like below:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $item){
    $item->setWild("your_content_here");
    $item->save();
}
```